# What is the dimension of $Graph(T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let there be $T:\mathbb{F^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{F^n}$ a linear transformation, and $Graph(T):=\{\,(v,T(v))\mid v\in \mathbb{F^n}\,\}$.

What is $\dim(Graph(T))$?

The answer is $n$ but if $Graph(T)$ is a order set of pair $(\mathbb{F^n},\mathbb{F^n})$ shouldnt the dimension be $2n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is about a *subspace* of $F^n\times F^n$, in fact about the image of the map $f:F^n\to F^n\times F^n$ given by $f:v\mapsto (v,T(v))$. Indeed the whole space has dimension$~2n$, but the subspace has dimension$~n$ only. It couldn't have been more, because the dimension of the image of $F^n$ under a linear map (which $f$ is) can never exceed$~n$. Here the image has dimension$~n$ exactly, because $f$ is injective; indeed if $p_1:F^n\times F^n\to F^n$ is $(v,w)\mapsto v$, then one has $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}$ which proves injectivity.

Comment: That is because the when choosing a vector $v$ one is sent to $(x,0)$ and the same one is mapped to $(0,Y)$, if T wouldn't get the same vector would it be $2n$?

Comment: @gbox: I don't understand you comment entirely. But if your question is about the subspace $\{\, (x,T(y))\mid x,y\in F^n\,\}$, then its dimension depends on $T$, and is $n+\operatorname{rank}(T)$; this _could_ be $2n$ (in which case the subspace is the whole space) but only if $T$ is surjective (and in fact invertible).

Comment: if $F^n=\mathbb{R^2}$ and $v=(2,2)$ and the $T$ transformation sends $T((1,0))=(0,1)$ and $T((0,1))=(1,0)$ so the Graph(T)=$(2(1,0)(0,1),2(0,1)(1,0))$ are there 4 basis?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $v=(2,2)$; there is no $v$ in the question (other than in the role of dummy variable for describing the graph). In your example Graph$(T)$ is a $2$-dimensional subspace of (the $4$-dimensional space) $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R^2$, spanned by the vectors $([1,0],[0,1])$ and $([0,1],[1,0])$ (and there are many other bases for the same subspace).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't contain all possible ordered pairs which is why it doesn't have dimension $2n$.

Note that the maps $f\colon\mathbb F^n \to \mathrm{Graph}(T)$ and $g\colon\mathrm{Graph}(T) \to \mathbb F^n$ defined by $f(v) = (v, T(v))$ and $g(v, w) = v$ are inverses, so $\mathrm{Graph}(T)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb F^n$ and hence has dimension $n$.

Comment: We wrote essentially the same answers simultaneously, and moreover chose the same names for our functions! (Only your $f$ has a restricted codomain w.r.t. mine, which is why it is an isomorphism.)

Comment: Why $ker(g)$ is just 0? Doesn't it sends $(0,y)\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: @gbox: Because here $g$ is defined on $\mathrm{Graph}(T)$ only, even though its defining expression does not reflect that. So $g(0,y)$ is defined _only_ if $y=T(0)$, in other words if $y=0$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Great minds think alike :)